# "Error when executing the ruleset" on the Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

When executing my rules deployed to the Business Rules service on Bluemix, I see  the following error:

> ilog.rules.res.decisionservice.IlrDecisionServiceException: Error when
>   executing the ruleset /MyRuleApp/1.0/myrules/1.0 
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.DecisionServiceController.executeRuleset(DecisionServiceController.java:262)
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.servlet.RESTDecisionServiceServlet.execute(RESTDecisionServiceServlet.java:930)
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.servlet.RESTDecisionServiceServlet.onMessage(RESTDecisionServiceServlet.java:843)
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.servlet.RESTDecisionServiceServlet.handleRequest(RESTDecisionServiceServlet.java:750)
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.servlet.RESTDecisionServiceServlet.doPost(RESTDecisionServiceServlet.java:737)
>   com.ibm.rules.htds.servlet.RESTDecisionServiceServlet.doPost(RESTDecisionServiceServlet.java:732)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the input data from the Bluemix console and realized that I was passing an incorrectly formed payload.

Instead of

```
{
    "foo": {
        "bar": "bar"
    }
}
```

I had missed the name of the input parameter "foo":

```
{
    {
        "bar": "bar"
    }
}
```

Once I passed  the correct input data to the rules, the rules executed successfully.